# Zoom-Scrolling not Working in Pigeon-Maps ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem with pigeon-maps in my reactjs-app. Using the mouse to navigate through the map works fine, but zooming with the scroll wheel does not work. However, a double-click zooms in the map, but then i have no way of zooming out again.

zoom and center are controlled variables.

```
<Map
      limitBounds='edge'
      center={center}
      onBoundsChanged={res => {setCenter(res.center); setZoom(res.zoom)}}
      zoom={zoom}
      provider={provider}
      onClick={changeLocation}
      width={width}
      height={height}
      zoomOnMouseWheel={true}
      animate={true}>
                {renderMarkers()}
</Map>
```

Once rendered the component looks like this:
[image: React-Component analyzer]

These are the dependencies i am using:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^13.9.0",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.23",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.5",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "pigeon-maps": "^0.14.0",
    "pigeon-overlay": "^0.2.3",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-router": "^5.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "^3.3.1",
    "react-spring": "^8.0.27",
    "react-use-clipboard": "1.0.2",
    "reactjs-popup": "^1.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.4.0",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3",
    "typescript": "^3.8.3"
}
```

If any of you have an Idea what might be causing my problem, i would be thankful if you shared it with me.

Best regards,

Koenigstein

edit: the whole code :

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import Map from "pigeon-maps";
import "./editor.css";

export default function EditorInterface(props) {
    const [selectedLocation, setSelectedLocation] = useState([0,0]);
    const defaultWidth = window.innerWidth * 0.6;
    const defaultHeight = window.innerHeight * .50 - 24;

    const [zoom, setZoom] = useState(13);
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(defaultWidth);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(defaultHeight);
    const [center, setCenter] = useState([49.750049, 6.637275]);


    const provider = (x, y, z) => {
        const s = String.fromCharCode(97 + (x + y + z) % 3);
        return `https://${s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png`
    };

    const changeLocation = (e) =>{
        setSelectedLocation(e.latLng);
    };



    return (
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div>
            <Map
            limitBounds='edge'
            center={center}
            onBoundsChanged={res => {setCenter(res.center); setZoom(res.zoom)}}
            zoom={zoom}
            provider={provider}
            onClick={changeLocation}
            width={width}
            height={height}
            zoomOnMouseWheel={true}
            animate={true}>
            </Map>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

The component is being used here:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Route} from "react-router-dom";
import AdminInterface from "./components/admininterface/AdminInterface";
import Watermark from "./components/watermark/Watermark";
import UserInterface from "./components/userinterface/UserInterface";
import EditorInterface from "./components/editorinterface/EditorInterface"

const App = () => {

    return (
        <Router>
            <Route exact path={"/"} render={() =>
                <UserInterface/>
            }/>
            <Route path={"/admin"} render={() =>
                <AdminInterface/>
            }/>
            <Route path={"/scenarioCreator"} render={() =>
                <EditorInterface/>
            }/>
            <Watermark/>
        </Router>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please post your entire code, basic example i have tried its working in chrome https://codesandbox.io/s/pigeon-maps-zoom-issue-nl439

Comment: Thanks for the fast comment. I posted the stripped version of my code now, it still doesnt work in my Application, but in the codesandbox.io environment it seems to work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will close this for now, because as DILEEP THOMAS pointed out, there is nothing wrong with the code, there seems to be something wrong with my project configuration or something else.

I will try to figure it out myself first.

Comment: Cool, happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

According to pigeon-maps docs, you need to press `(cmd/win) key` while zooming with the mouse wheel

> metaWheelZoom - Zooming with the mouse wheel only works when you hold down the meta (cmd/win) key. Defaults to false.

Docs here : https://github.com/mariusandra/pigeon-maps

Comment: You only need to do this if metaWheelZoom is set to false which it isnt (by default). Also then an error-message would appear on the map (you need to press cmd/win to scroll)